# What is a partial chi-square statistic according to Frank Harrell?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, predictive-models

In his RMS course (section 4.1.1), Frank Harrell mentions the use of a partial chi square statistic for measuring the strength of association between a predictor and an outcome. See below for a screenshot of this passage:

[image]

Given a model, the differences between partial chi-squares and their respective degrees of freedom can be plotted using `plot(anova(mod)`.  Here is an example

[image]

From what test are these chi-squares obtained?  How might I compute these quantities in base R?

Comment: I think these are just analogous to 'Type III sums of squares' tests.  In R, you could use `drop1(model, test="Chi")`. You can think of it as a measure of effect size after you've accounted for the differences in dfs.

Answer (score 4):

For other than ordinary least squares (OLS) regression, the `anova()` function in Harrell's [`rms` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rms) performs Wald tests on individual coefficients and sets of related coefficients; Wald tests are an option for OLS models. The Wald $\chi^2$ statistic used in the test for a coefficient or a set of coefficients is the "partial $\chi^2$ statistic."

The code is in the `ava()` function defined at the start of `rms:::anova.rms`. For a vector of coefficient estimates `coefs` and the corresponding subset of the covariance matrix `vcov(coefs)`, it's just the quadratic form combining the `coefs` with the inverse of `vcov(coefs)`. See [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/591213/28500) for a simple implementation in base R. Subtracting the number of degrees of freedom corrects for the mean $\chi^2$ under the null hypothesis.

For OLS, `plot.anova.rms()` by default multiplies similar partial *F*-statistics by the (numerator) degrees of freedom to get $\chi^2$ values. It can, upon request, display corresponding partial $R^2$ values.

Answer (score 4):

This is an appendix to @EdM answer (+1). I look at the implementation (in base R) to make sure I understand the partial $\chi^2$ statistic. The R code borrows heavily from the [rms::anova](https://github.com/harrelfe/rms/blob/master/R/anova.rms.s). This is for illustration only, so there are restrictions; most importantly, it's assumed the predictors have unique names.

```r
library("rms")

getHdata(nhgh)

g <- function(x) 0.09 - x^-(1 / 1.75)
formula <- g(gh) ~ rcs(age, 4) + re + sex + rcs(bmi, 4)
plot(anova(
  ols(formula, data = nhgh)
))
```

[image]

```r
# Fit model in base R
model <- lm(formula, data = nhgh)

# `age` is transformed into a restricted cubic spline with 4 knots,
# so there are 3 components.
associated_terms(model, "age")
#> [1] "rcs(age, 4)age"   "rcs(age, 4)age'"  "rcs(age, 4)age''"
```

The partial $\chi^2$ statistic is $\hat{\beta}_{S}^\top\widehat{\Sigma}_{S}^{-1}\hat{\beta}_S$ where $S$ is the set of terms associated with the predictor (linear, nonlinear, interactions), $\hat{\beta}_S$ is the corresponding subset of coefficient estimates and $\widehat{\Sigma}_S$ is their covariance matrix.

```r
rbind(
  partial_chisq(model, "sex"),
  partial_chisq(model, "re"),
  partial_chisq(model, "bmi"),
  partial_chisq(model, "age")
)
#>   predictor       chi2 df             P
#> 1       sex   15.17428  1  9.802941e-05
#> 2        re  172.89056  4  2.506276e-36
#> 3       bmi  332.38234  3  9.730894e-72
#> 4       age 1324.07373  3 8.795631e-287
```

---

The R implementation in full.

```r
library("rms")

# Find model terms which are a function of the given predictor,
# including (linear and nonlinear) main effects and interactions.
#
# @param model: A fitted `lm` or `glm` model.
# @param predictor: The name of a single predictor.
#
# Caution!
# This function assumes predictors have unique names.
associated_terms <- function(model, predictor) {
  terms <- names(coef(model))
  terms[grepl(predictor, terms, perl = TRUE)]
}

# Compute t(x) @ inv(V) @ x
# @param V: a square n-by-n matrix.
# @param x: a n-dimensional vector.
compute_quadratic <- function(V, x) {
  x %*% solvet(V, x, tol = 1e-9)
}

# Compute the Wald chi squared statistic for a subset of model terms.
partial_chisq <- function(model, predictor) {
  terms <- associated_terms(model, predictor)

  b <- coef(model)
  V <- vcov(model)

  idx <- names(b) %in% terms

  chi2 <- compute_quadratic(V[idx, idx], b[idx])
  df <- sum(idx)

  data.frame(
    predictor, chi2, df,
    P = pchisq(chi2, df, lower.tail = FALSE)
  )
}


# BBR, Section 4.3.5
getHdata(nhgh)

g <- function(x) 0.09 - x^-(1 / 1.75)
ginverse <- function(y) (0.09 - y)^-1.75

formula <- g(gh) ~ rcs(age, 4) + re + sex + rcs(bmi, 4)
plot(anova(
  ols(formula, data = nhgh)
))

# Fit model in base R
model <- lm(formula, data = nhgh)

# `age` is transformed into a restricted cubic spline with 4 knots,
# so there are 3 components.
associated_terms(model, "age")

rbind(
  partial_chisq(model, "sex"),
  partial_chisq(model, "re"),
  partial_chisq(model, "bmi"),
  partial_chisq(model, "age")
)

# BBR, Section 19.8
getHdata(acath)
acath <- subset(acath, !is.na(choleste))

formula <- sigdz ~ sex * rcs(age, 5)
plot(anova(
  lrm(formula, data = acath)
))

# Fit model in base R
model <- glm(formula, family = binomial, data = acath)

# The "contribution" of `age` includes a restricted cubuc spline *and*
# the interaction with `sex`.
associated_terms(model, "age")

rbind(
  partial_chisq(model, "age"),
  partial_chisq(model, "sex")
)
```

Comment: Good answers above.  To see exactly which parameters are being tested you can do `print(anova(...), which='subscripts' or 'names' or 'dots')` which augments the ANOVA table.  Also think of the partial $\chi^2$ as proportional to semipartial $R^2$.

Comment: I think you are missing the inverse indicator on the covariance matrix in the quadratic form for the partial chi-square. Other than that, looks good! (+1)